# Cannot run JDK7 java in cmd, but javac works

Tags: java, jdk

I just recently installed JDK7 and then afterwards I uninstalled it because I couldn't run java from command line in Windows7. I tried to reinstall JDK7 after uninstalling it, but it doesn't help. When I input java in command line I get the following.

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this problem? I tried to google and none of the answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like registry keys are some how altered.

Open registry editor (search in start menu) and go to the path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7`, and see if following entries exist or not.

`JavaHome`  `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

`Microversion`  `0`

`RuntimeLib`  `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll`

Also, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7`, and look for following key.

`JavaHome`  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0`

`Microversion`  `0`

If above keys do not exist, instead of creating them manually, I would recommend you to remove currently installed JDK 7 and make a fresh installation of the [same](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u1-download-513651.html).

Once done, add following paths to their respective environment variables.

`classpath`     `C:\Program Files\Java\<jdk folder>\lib ;`

`path`          `C:\Program Files\Java\<jdk folder>\bin`

And than try running `java` and `javac`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have those entries in the registry, and I tried to reinstall JDK7 many times already. All times with the same results

Comment: You may want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key)

Comment: Also, uninstall JDK and delete respective registry keys to and than make clean install, since most of the applications never delete their registry entries even if they are uninstalled.

Comment: how do i know which entry I should delete, or can it be safe to say that each entry which say java is ok to delete? Like is the entire `JavaSoft` ok to remove (located in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft`)?

Comment: ok after some play around, reinstall, uninstall, remove different stuff from registry, and restoring the registry, finally JDK7 works as it should work. I don't know what the problem still was though....